# Search string across two fields mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with two fields: FirstName and LastName. I want to provide search functionality where someone can type in either first name, last name or first name + last name. I am trying to find a way to search the collection by concatenating the FirstName and LastName fields together so that the search works.

Currently, I have this:

```
collection.find( { $or: [{'nameFirst': {$regex: name}}, {'nameLast': {$regex: name}}] } ).toArray( (queryError, docs) => {
            docs = docs.map( (p) => {return new Player(p)});
            resolve(docs);
            db.close();
          })
```

However, if I type in 'John Smith', the search doesn't return anything because 'John' and 'Smith' are in two separate columns. Is there an easy way to do this without having to split up my search text box into a firstname textbox and a lastname textbox or by having to create an additional column in my collection with the concatenated value of FirstName + LastName?

Aggregation looks like it might provide a little bit of help but i'm not finding a solid example that's explaining how to approach it. I also can see a possable solution by simple doing a `.split(' ')` on the search term but that would mean I would have to do extra logic because there's not guarentee that the user will type it in First Name and then Last Name. They could type in LastName and then First Name